# PWA not sharing file with navigator.share, only dowload

Tags: javascript, android, angular, progressive-web-apps

This is my code

```js
    let f: any = XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.generarNombre(pedido.folio), {
          bookType: 'xlsx',
          type: 'array'
        })
    
        let data: Blob = new Blob([f], { type: EXCEL_TYPE })
        let file = new File([data], this.generarNombre(pedido.folio), {
          type: EXCEL_TYPE
        })
    
        let navigator = window.navigator as any
    
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let data = {
            files: [file],
            title: this.generarNombre(pedido.folio),
            text: pedido.folio
          }
          if (navigator.canShare(data))
            navigator.share(data).then(result => resolve(result))
          else reject('No soportado por el dispositivo')
        })
      }
```

My application is a PWA and it is installed successfully in android, the problem is that instead of sharing with the native option of android it only downloads the file. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can implement directly and check this out as in web.dev [here](https://web.dev/web-share/#sharing-files)
2. Or better use this pwa library, [pwafire](https://docs.pwafire.org/web-share);

   ```
    pwa.Share({
    // Title of what to share
    title: "Some title..",
    // Text to share
    text: "Some text...",
    // List of files to share...
    files: file_list
   ```

   };)